# How do you simplify brackets using the dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Write $(((a\times b)\times a)\times b)\times a\cdot b$, where $a\cdot b = p$, $a\cdot a = q$, and $b\cdot b = r$ in terms of only dot products.

EDIT:

The answer was $(((a\times b)\times a)\times b)\times a\cdot b=((qb−pa)\times b)\times a\cdot b=0−p(a\times b)\times a\cdot b=−p(qb−pa)\cdot b=−p(qr−p2)$, unfortunately i didnt get it on time, but thanks for the help

Comment: Statement looks funny.  The last term in the cross product expression is a scalar (a.b), unless you imply a missing ).

Comment: @DavidGStork By taking out the last line, you have removed what some users would consider "useful context" from the asker

Comment: @Charlie If it was only $(a \times b) \times a) \cdot b$, would you have any idea how to proceed? Could you tell us how you came across this problem?

Comment: The scalar a.b at the end was also confusing me, the answer was (((a×b)×a)×b)×a⋅b=((qb−pa)×b)×a⋅b=0−p(a×b)×a⋅b=−p(qb−pa)⋅b=−p(qr−p2)

Comment: It was on an assignment that was due 10 minutes before i asked this question

Comment: @CharlieMohammedHurley An assignment in what class? It would be helpful to have an indication of the kind of approach expected

Comment: @CharlieMohammedHurley Have you encountered "summation notation" or the [Levi-Cevita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol)?

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/482320/81360) is related

Answer (score 1):

Recall the triple vector product
$$
(a\times b)\times c=(c\cdot a)b-(c\cdot b)a
$$
and proceed to simplify the given expression:
\begin{align*}
[(((a\times b)\times a)\times b), a, b]
&=[((a\cdot a)b-(a\cdot b)a)\times b), a, b]\\
&=\dots
\end{align*}